# Persist array data in struts 2.0

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, arraylist

I am using struts 2.0 in a project.I am having a form which takes user information. The condition is user can add details of  n number of users and when he press submit button we need to take data of all the user and store it in database. I have created a pojo and for every user details I am creating a object and trying to store it in a array.
But everytime I call the class the object is getting reinitialised. How can I persist the array without making it static. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `List<T>` instead of array and `Session` to maintain the *state*.

Comment: can you show the code else its Hard what and how things going on

Comment: Thanks AVD I will try this and will let you know. Umesh at same time I will paste the code.